# Parametrisation of the surface a torus

Tags: calculus, parametric

For a calculus question  I need to parameterise the surface of the torus generated by rotating the circle given by $(x-b)^2+z^2=a^2$ around the $z$-axis (with $0<a<b$).
I've had a go at this, and have come up with $$\vec{r}(\theta,\phi)=((a\cos\theta+b)\cos\phi, (a\cos\theta+b)\sin\phi, a\sin\theta), ~~ \theta,\phi\in [0,2\pi].$$

I haven't done anything like this for a while now, so I've kind of forgotten how it all goes. So I've tried plotting this on WolframAlpha to see if it's correct, but I can't get it to actually plot a surface defined in this way. I have a copy of Matlab, is there any way I could plot this surface on there to see if it's correct? Basically how can I check if I'm right or not? Failing that, could somebody please just point out if I'm wrong?

Comment: as a British English speaker I'm pretty sure 'parameterise' is fine, but thanks for the edit anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your formula is absolutely correct, just look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry) for verification.

Comment: cannot believe I didn't think to check Wikipedia, sorry! but thank you very much

Comment: @Tim no problem.

Answer (score 6):

A circle of radius $a$ centered at $(b,0)$ in the plane $xz$ has the parametric equation

$$x=a\cos(\theta)+b,z=a\sin(\theta),$$ with $\theta$ in the range $[0,2\pi]$ for a full circle.

Now you rotate the plane $xz$ around $z$ by $x\leftarrow x\cos(\phi),y\leftarrow x\sin(\phi)$,  with $\phi$ in the range $[0,2\pi]$ for a full turn,

$$x=(a\cos(\theta)+b)\cos(\phi),\\
y=(a\cos(\theta)+b)\sin(\phi),\\
z=a\sin(\theta).$$

If you freeze $\theta$, you get a circle in a plane parallel to $xy$, of the form:

$$x=r\cos(\phi),y=r\sin(\phi).$$

Answer (score 4):

You can plot this surface in WolframAlpha.  The correct syntax to use is:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 Cos[u]+3) Cos[v], (2 Cos[u]+3) Sin[v], 2 Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

where I have chosen $a = 2$, $b = 3$.  [The output looks like this.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot3D[%7B%282%20Cos[u]%2B3%29%20Cos[v],%20%282%20Cos[u]%2B3%29%20Sin[v],%202%20Sin[u]%7D,%20%7Bu,0,2%20Pi%7D,%20%7Bv,0,2%20Pi%7D])

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MATLAB code:

```
[phi,theta] = meshgrid(linspace(0,2*pi),linspace(0,2*pi));

r = 1; b = 3;

x = (r.*cos(theta)+b).*cos(phi);
y = (r.*cos(theta)+b).*sin(phi);
z = (r.*sin(theta));
s = surf(x,y,z);

alpha(s,0.5)

shading flat

axis equal
```

Run this in script (or quickly in Command Window).