# Parametrizing a Torus

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

I am currently studying Geometry, and am having trouble parametrizing a Torus. The Torus is defined as being the surface of revolution by rotating the circle:
$$y^2+(z-a)^2=r^2, \>\> x=0$$About the $y$-axis. We assume that $a>r>0$. 
Now, I believe the parametrization for the circle is given by:
$$\phi(r,\theta)=(0, r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta)-a)$$
How would the Torus be parametrized as I rotate it about the $y$-axis?

Comment: Hint: pick a point on your circle and think about what an angle of rotation around the $y$-axis does to it. How do you map it back to the circle?

Comment: Why haven't you first googled "torus parameterisation" ? See (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/358825)

Comment: @Lee Mosher We have converged to the same reference